# JSHint: Overwrite single .jshintrc option for whole folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, jshint

I have a `.jshintrc` at the root of my project with the following configuration:

```
{
  "node": true,
  "smarttabs": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true
}
```

This is fine for all the node related stuff I have in the project, but not for the browser related scripts. Which are sitting in a subfolder.
Is it possible overwrite just the `node` option while preserving the other options for a whole folder?

If I create another `.jshintrc` file for the browser side folder I have to tell JSHint again about all my configurations, although I actually just want to unset the `node` option.

I know that I can set this option in every file but I actually would like to avoid that.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is not possible, unfortunately. It *is* possible with Grunt though (with the grunt-contrib-jshint task). That allows you to override specific options in specific targets.

Comment: @James Thank you. Since I'm already using Grunt for the project I'll surely take a look at the plugin.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, there's a feature in **jshint v2.5.1** that is "extends", for your example this could be like this:

/.jshintrc

```
{
  "smarttabs": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true
}
```

/server/.jshintrc

```
{
  "extends": "../.jshintrc",
  "node": true
}
```

/client/.jshintrc

```
{
  "extends": "../.jshintrc",
  "browser": true
}
```

You can read more about this feature here:
https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.1

Comment: Wow, you seriously revived this question? Nevertheless thank you for the answer, I'm sure I'll have use for it in the future.

Comment: Huzzah! Just found this when I needed it :)